# How do you have a title stay at the bottom of the page and then scroll when it is passed by?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tags

I'm working on some content for my page and I was wondering how I would be able to have a title of the next paragraph stay at the bottom while I'm reading the first but then scroll with the page when I pass by it?

I've tried to look it up but I have had no luck even finding something that would help. I'm just not sure what the effect I'm trying to do is called.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use offset, scrollTop properties, thats your clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I understood, you would want something like **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/bae06vff/)**?

```js
var title = [];

$('.title').each(function() {
    title.push($(this));
});

$(window).scroll( function() {
    var bottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    for (var i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
        if (bottom > title[i].offset().top) {
            $('.currentTitle').text(title[i + 1].text());
        }
    }
    console.log(bottom);
});
```

```css
.content > h1 {
    margin-top: 300px;
}

.currentTitle {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <h1 class="title"> title 1 </h1>
    <p> text 1 </p>
    <h1 class="title"> title 2 </h1>
    <p> text 2 </p>
    <h1 class="title"> title 3 </h1>
    <p> text 3 </p>
    <p class="currentTitle"> title 1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, but you are spot on! That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I made this code 'fast' you might need to polish it a little i.e, this will never go back to title 1 !! and will keep displaying last title even you already passed it !! :)

Comment: Will do! At least I have a basis to work from which is more than enough! Thanks again.